# Is there a MSVC 2013 std::list memory leak?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, allocator

https://ideone.com/dA1Km2

This is a link to a simple example program. It defines a custom allocator which counts the difference between the allocations and deallocations.

It creates and then destroys an empty `std::list`.

When it is built with gcc or clang (as in the link) it outputs 0. This is expected - the deallocations should be the same number as the allocations.

However MSVC 2013 outputs 2. Two allocations are made by this empty `std::list`, which are not deallocated later.

Is this a memory leak? If not, what happens there, and is there a way to really clear the `std::list` specific memory in msvc?

Comment: MSVC++ has a good debugger, you haven't spent enough time using it.  Just setting a breakpoint on your allocate() and deallocate() functions shows your bug.

Comment: I must admit I'm really not seeing it :) What is the bug?

Comment: Apparently my custom delete operator doesn't call the destructor. I still can't figure out why.

Comment: Bingo.  Rather bad, isn't it?

Comment: True. I was expecting that overloading the delete operator would call the destructors (as overloading new calls the constructors). Apparently I wasn't correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leak is in your own code:  Your `custom_delete` fails to call the destructor for the `std::list` object--it directly calls `operator delete` to deallocate the memory without invoking the destructor.

If you fix your program to correctly destroy the list, you will observe no leak (the program prints 0):

```
auto x = custom_new custom_list<int>;
x->~list(); // Destroy the list
custom_delete(x);
std::cout << the_manager.allocations << std::endl;
```

So, why do you only see the leak with the Visual C++ `std::list` implementation?  The Visual C++ implementation always allocates a sentinel node for empty list objects, to ensure that when a list is moved (or when two lists are swapped), end iterators are not invalidated.  The Standard Library implementation(s) that you are using with gcc and clang apparently do not do this.

Comment: Yep. Apparently I don't know how to overload the delete operator :)